# Is there a base R function to dynamically order data.frame columns similar to dplyr everything()?

Tags: r

Suppose you have a data.frame, and you wish to dynamically re-order the columns using base R. The input data will always look something like this. It will always contain the `id`, `month`, and `year` variables, as well as a variable number of data variables (denoted as `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc.)

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  v1 = LETTERS[1:5],
  v2 = rep(2,5),
  v3 = rep(10,5),
  month = c("jan", "jan", "mar", "oct", "dec"),
  year = c(1999, 2001, 1984, 1979, 2019),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to re-order the columns such that `id`, `month`, and `year` are always the first three columns, and then place the data variables beginning in column 4.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  month = c("jan", "jan", "mar", "oct", "dec"),
  year = c(1999, 2001, 1984, 1979, 2019),
  v1 = LETTERS[1:5],
  v2 = rep(2,5),
  v3 = rep(10,5),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I am aware this can be done with `dplyr::select` along with `dplyr::everything`.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% select(id, month, year, everything())
```

But I would like to achieve the same output using base R.

The best I have come up with is,

```
keep1 <- c("id", "month", "year")
keep2 <- names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% keep1]
keep3 <- c(keep1, keep2)
df2 <- df1[, keep3]
```

Might there be a more elegant solution? Like, might there be a function in base R similar to `dplyr::everything`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `setdiff`:

```
df1[, c(keep1, setdiff(names(df1), keep1))]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
df1[order(match(names(df1), keep1, nomatch = NCOL(df1) + 1))]
#  id month year v1 v2 v3
#1  1   jan 1999  A  2 10
#2  2   jan 2001  B  2 10
#3  3   mar 1984  C  2 10
#4  4   oct 1979  D  2 10
#5  5   dec 2019  E  2 10
```

Comment: Nice, I actually prefer this solution because it doesn’t repeat `keep1`, and therefore allows specifying the names directly without storing them in a variable first.

Answer (score 5):

Another option

```
df1[, unique(c(which(names(df1) %in% keep1), seq_along(df1)))]
```

or

```
df1[, unique(c("id", "month", "year", names(df1)))]
```

Comment: The second solution is pretty neat!